# Why is extract week from current_date giving wrong week number

Tags: sql, date, select, google-bigquery, date-arithmetic

`select extract(week from current_date)` is giving 16 but current ISO week is 17.
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? Last week it worked OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for:

```
extract(isoweek from current_date)
```

As per **[the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions?hl=en)**:

> `WEEK`: Returns the week number of the date in the range `[0, 53]`. Weeks begin with Sunday, and dates prior to the first Sunday of the year are in week 0.
>
> `ISOWEEK`: Returns the [ISO 8601 week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) number of the date_expression. `ISOWEEK`s begin on Monday. Return values are in the range `[1, 53]`. The first `ISOWEEK` of each ISO year begins on the Monday before the first Thursday of the Gregorian calendar year.